# How do I make a script schedule a large number of tasks all at once?

Tags: python, arrays, list, datetime, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to write a script which will schedule a bunch of tasks to be executed at certain times. I have a large number of tasks to schedule and they change all the time, so the only realistic way to implement it is with a loop. 
So far I have:

```
for i in range(len(timetable)):
    try:
        h = int(timetable[i].split(":")[0])+7
        m = int(timetable[i].split(":")[1])-7
        if m < 0:
            h = h -1
            m = m +60
        schedule.every(1).day.at(str(h)+":"+str(m)).do(execute(i))
    except:
        pass

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

My problem is that when I run this block of code instead of scheduling the tasks to their assigned time it just runs them in succession.

Thanks.

Comment: what is this `schedule` ?

Comment: What do you mean by `they change all the time`?

Comment: Schedule is this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule , only thing I could find for the job. By "they change all the time" I mean that the script pulls data from an excel spreadsheet that gets changed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you should not execute your tasks within do like `do(execute(i)) # f() will execute your f function rather than schedule them`. You should define your tasks as different functions and call their name only during scheduling.

For example:

```
# Task 1 
def task1():
    ...

# Task 2
def task2():
    ...

# Task 3
def task3():
    ...
```

Then schedule them as

```
schedule.every(1).day.at(str(h)+":"+str(m)).do(task1)
schedule.every(1).day.at(str(h)+":"+str(m)).do(task2)
schedule.every(1).day.at(str(h)+":"+str(m)).do(task3)
```

NOT

```
schedule.every(1).day.at(str(h)+":"+str(m)).do(task1()) # this will execute your task
```

If you want to work with loop, define your task function inside another function regarding index number i and let that function return your task function, such as

```
def taski(i): # indexed function, which return a function
    def task():
        ... # content of your task function
        return ... # return of your task function 
    return task # the return of your index function taski should be your task function, again only name here, no ()
```

Then schedule inside your loop with calling the index function with i

```
schedule.every(1).day.at(str(h)+":"+str(m)).do(taski(i))
# now taski(i) will not execute your task, 
# since it returns 'task' which is another function without execution
```